# Flask-security: registration processing renders user.role_id may not be NULL error

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am trying to make registration in my Flask app work. I have already created two roles ("admin" and "user") and one admin (me) without any problems. However, when I try to register a new user through the registration page, I get the following error:

```
user.role_id may not be NULL
```

Models (standard quickstart):
    class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
        name = CharField(unique=True)
        description = TextField(null=True)

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    email = TextField()
    password = TextField()
    active = BooleanField(default=True)
    confirmed_at = DateTimeField(null=True)

class UserRoles(db.Model):
    # Because peewee does not come with built-in many-to-many
    # relationships, we need this intermediary class to link
    # user to roles.
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='roles')
    role = ForeignKeyField(Role, related_name='users')
    name = property(lambda self: self.role.name)
    description = property(lambda self: self.role.description)
```

I really don't get where this is coming from. Firstly, you don't need to assign a role to a new user, and secondly, since 'role' is a foreign key, the correct way to get the users' role id would be `user.role.id` instead of `user.role_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have had a `role` foreign key at one point on your User table, but maybe you removed it?  You may need to alter your table to drop the column if you're not using it anymore.